# Oracle SQL Count orders by customers in the last 10 days based on order id

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by, count

In Oracle SQL my goal is to receive the total number of orders made by a customer in the last 10 days but shown by the order id and not the customer id.

The following situation is given:

[image]

My desired outcome is:

[image]

How can I facilitate this in the most efficient way?

Comment: That output makes no sense for the given data. Describe decision logic you followed to derive those numbers.

Comment: Based on a certain order id I want to know how many orders a customer has made in the last 10 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use self-join with date of subtraction condition, the condition need to judge what rows are during 10 days

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.Customer_ID,
       t1.Order_NR,
       COUNT(*) Number_Orders
FROM T t1 
INNER JOIN T t2
ON t1.Customer_ID = t2.Customer_ID AND t2.Order_Date BETWEEN t1.Order_Date - 10 AND t1.Order_Date
GROUP BY t1.Customer_ID,
       t1.Order_NR
ORDER BY t1.Order_NR
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7aa2d/1/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_NR | NUMBER_ORDERS |
|-------------|----------|---------------|
|         100 |        1 |             1 |
|         200 |        2 |             1 |
|         300 |        3 |             1 |
|         100 |        4 |             2 |
|         100 |        5 |             2 |
|         200 |        6 |             1 |
|         700 |        7 |             1 |
|         800 |        8 |             2 |
|         800 |        9 |             2 |
|         800 |       10 |             3 |
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One question though: How would you change the query if want not only the amount of orders over 10 days, but also the amount over 30 days in the same query? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a self-join and can simply use the `COUNT` analytic function with a `RANGE` window:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       order_no,
       order_date,
       COUNT(*) OVER (
         PARTITION BY customer_id
         ORDER BY order_date
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '10' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '0' DAY FOLLOWING
       ) AS numer_orders
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY order_no
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (customer_id, order_no, order_date) AS
SELECT 100,  1, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200,  2, DATE '2021-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300,  3, DATE '2021-01-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100,  4, DATE '2021-01-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100,  5, DATE '2021-01-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200,  6, DATE '2021-01-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 700,  7, DATE '2021-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800,  8, DATE '2021-01-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800,  9, DATE '2021-01-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 800, 10, DATE '2021-01-28' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_NO | ORDER_DATE | NUMER_ORDERS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 1 | 01-JAN-21 | 1 |
> | 200 | 2 | 02-JAN-21 | 1 |
> | 300 | 3 | 05-JAN-21 | 1 |
> | 100 | 4 | 09-JAN-21 | 2 |
> | 100 | 5 | 15-JAN-21 | 2 |
> | 200 | 6 | 18-JAN-21 | 1 |
> | 700 | 7 | 20-JAN-21 | 1 |
> | 800 | 8 | 25-JAN-21 | 2 |
> | 800 | 9 | 25-JAN-21 | 2 |
> | 800 | 10 | 28-JAN-21 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4b1771768339e4faf03b680be85359a7)*